# Arduino esp8266 EEPROM lag

Tags: esp8266

Trying to save my LED-State to EEPROM.

After every 5 seconds my EEPROM saves the value of white in this example (didn't put in RGB yet)

When the EEPROM gets commited and the value changes the LED is dark for a few milliseconds

what can I do?

```
int xInt = wVal.toInt();
white_val = xInt;
controlLed(whitePin, xInt);
```

Triggers LED:

```
void controlLed(int pin, int integer) {
  analogWrite(pin, integer); 
  return;
}
```

Loop Saving Data every five seconds:

```
void loop() {
  static unsigned long startTemp = 0;
  unsigned long msTime = millis();

  if (msTime - startTemp >= 5000) {
    startTemp = msTime;
    writeEeprom(white_address, white_val);
  }
}
```

Writes Data to EEPROM:

```
void writeEeprom(int address, int value) {
  EEPROM.put(address, value);
  Serial.println("WRITTEN  TO EEPROM:");
  Serial.println(address);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(value);
  Serial.print("\n");
  EEPROM.commit();

  EEPROM.get(address,value);
  Serial.println("READ  FROM EEPROM:");
  Serial.println(address);
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.println(value);
  Serial.print("\n");
  return;
}
```

Comment: What's the GPIO number of the pin you're using to control the LED?

Comment: `
const int whitePin = 14;
`
It's a esp8266 ESP-07

Comment: the first snippet is from setup()? which version of esp8226 Arduino core you use?

Comment: No the first snippet gets triggered when the value changes   
`
           if(text.startsWith("w")){
            
            String wVal=(text.substring(text.indexOf("w")+1,text.length())); 
            int wInt = wVal.toInt();
            white_val = wInt;
            controlLed(whitePin, wInt);
            webSocket.sendTXT(num, "white changed", lenght);
           }
`

   Latest Stable:
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json

   And Arduino 1.8.7
   esp8266 has version 2.4.2